# COUNTIFS with no duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a worksheet with:

- countries (some of them are duplicated), and
- different project stages

A "1" is written in the correct product stage column when a country has reached that stage. I would like to count how many "1:s"/countries that have reached each product stage, while not counting the same country twice even if it is listed several times.

[image: 1]

I've tried to use the COUNTIFS function but I'm not sure how to exclude the duplicates while having a column criteria. I do not want to use pivot tables in this case, since I will do this count on several worksheets. Simplified version can be seen in the picture below.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include both your attempted formula *and* let us know what version of Excel you are running.

Comment: Yes, I'm running version 1908 of Excel... My attempted formula only counted all the ones including the duplicates. Basically only referring to worksheet 1 and counting all the "1":s in a column. I didn't know how to write one to exclude them.

=COUNTIFS(WS1!D:D;1)

Comment: What I meant was: Excel 2019, Excel O365, Excel 2016 or otherwise?

Comment: Ah thanks, Excel O365

Answer (score 2):

In Excel O365 you could try:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B=1)))
```

This would get you the count of unique values for stage 1.

Comment: Thank you, but it says the function is not valid when I try it...

Comment: @Soph And what is your version of Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld O365 ProPlus

Comment: @Soph you should be receiving that feature in the near future, unless your administrator has updates turned off.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RonRosenfeld! I'll check it up with the administrator :)